# how to prove that regular language is closed under concatenation using DFA?

Tags: math, computer-science, computation-theory

We've learned how to use NFA to prove that closure property, but how could we do that without any help of using the conception of NFA? How to construct a DFA that could solve this problem?
(so translating a proof of using NFA into DFA is forbidden)

I've tried to construct is by making $Q=P(Q_1*Q2)$, and represent it with steps, however failed...

Comment: I seriously doubt there is a trivial proof using DFA's of closure over concatenation.  Determining the border between the left and right side of the concatenation is itself a non-deterministic action.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously think this is a hard problem.  Imagine that language L1 is `(aaaaaaaaa)*`, and L2 is `(aaaaaaaaaa)*`.  That is, all multiple of 9 a's and all multiples of 10 a's, respectively.

The DFA for L1 and L2 are each pretty easy to draw, with 9 and 10 states respectively.

But the DFA for L1 | L2 accepts strings of "a" that is a multiple of 9 plus a multiple of 10. You're going to have a hard time creating a simple DFA that accepts `'a'*70` [72 a's in a row] and `'a'* 72`, but not `'a'*71` without somehow using an NFA as an intermediate step.